# NLog Memory Target is not generating logs

Tags: c#, memory, nlog

I am just adding the memory target for generating the logs it does not  generate the logs from memory target

My N Log config file -  [[[[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIg55.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XUAy.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DjFL.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQOoB.png)

My Get Live Logs method that is used to retrieve the logs from  the memory target but it is not it says that log Message count is equal to 0 .  but my file target is working fine it generate the logs and storing them in a file
[method which retrieve the logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SNeS.png)

Comment: Consider enabling `throwConfigExceptions="true"` when troubleshooting NLog configuration. It can also be useful to enable [NLog InternalLogger](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging) and check for warnings and errors. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting

Comment: My NLog.config file is successfully added and registered memory target but still it is not generating the logs

Comment: I would verify that you have configured the NLog.config Rules-section correctly to redirect to your memory-target. You can also check the [NLog InternalLogger](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging) to verify your Logger is correctly configured to output to memory-target. Ensure that you are logging with the expected LogLevel. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting